# GLPaint based OpenGL ES Blending Issue

Tags: ios, opengl-es, blending, alphablending

I'm working on an app based on Apple's GLPaint sample code. I've changed the clear color to transparent black and have added an opacity slider, however when I mix colors together with a low opacity setting they don't mix the way I'm expecting. They seem to mix the way light mixes, not the way paint mixes. Here is an example of what I mean:

[image]

The "Desired Result" was obtained by using glReadPixels to render each color separately and merge it with the previous rendered image (i.e. using apple's default blending).

However, mixing each frame with the previous is too time consuming to be done on the fly, how can I get OpenGL to blend the colors properly? I've been researching online for quite a while and have yet to find a solution that works for me, please let me know if you need any other info to help!

Comment: Will be please share the link which you are using as sample code / any such link.. That will be better to understand your problem. Because in openGL we need to set several Blending options and blending functions.

Comment: My code is based on Apple's GLPaint code which can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the looks of it, with your current setup, there is no easy solution. For what you are trying to do, you need custom shaders. Which is not possible using just GLKit.

Luckily you can mix GLKit and OpenGL ES.

**My recommendation would be to:**

1. Stop using GLKit for everything except setting up your rendering
   surface with GLKView (which is tedious without GLKit).
2. Use an OpenGl program with custom shaders to draw to a texture that is backing an FBO.
3. Use a second program with custom shaders that does post processing (after drawing above texture to a quad which is then rendered to the screen).

A good starting point would be to load up the OpenGl template that comes with Xcode. And start modifying it. Be warned: If you don't understand shaders, the code here will make little sense. It draws 2 cubes, one using GLKit, and one without - using custom shaders.

**References to start learning:**

- [Intro to shaders](http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Chapter-2.2:-Shaders.html)
- [Rendering to a Texture](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH103-SW7)
- [Shader Toy](https://www.shadertoy.com/) - This should help you experiment with your post processing frag shader.
- [GLEssentials example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/GLEssentials/Introduction/Intro.html) - This shows how to render to texture using OpenGL ( a bit outdated.)

Finally, if you are really serious about using OpenGL ES to it's full potential, you really should invest the time to read through [OpenGL ES 2.0 programming guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321502795). Even though it is 6 years old, it is still relevant and the only book I've found that explains all the concepts correctly.

Comment: This is a very 'complete' answer, thankyou. My setup does indeed employ a custom shader, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to setup solution #2, but I'll keep researching and I'm sure I'll figure it out eventually, you've linked some great resources, and being the best answer I think you deserve the bounty. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your "Current Result" is additive color, which is how OpenGL is supposed to work.  To work like mixing paint would be substractive color.  You don't have control over this with OpenGL ES 1.1, but you could write a custom fragment shader for OpenGL ES 2.0 that would do substractive color.  If you are blending textures images from iOS, you need to know if the image data has been premultiplied by alpha or not, in order to do blending.  OpenGL ES expects the non-premultiplied format.

Comment: I am using OpenGL ES 2.0, can you point me in the right direction to look for tips on writing the shader, I am unfamiliar with GLSL.

Comment: You really need a good tutorial SDK and this one is the best: http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdkdownloads/index.asp  Also, checkout my blog at http://montgomery1.com/opengl/

Comment: I read somewhere that a custom shader wouldn't work because you don't have access to the destination pixel color from within the shader, requiring that I rely on the limited blend functions available?

Comment: It's possible to work around that using 2 rendering passes.  The first would render to a texture attached to an FBO.  Then, read that back through a custom shader as a second texture.

Comment: You do have access to the destination fragment color *on iOS* (just not using the core OpenGL ES spec). See [Apple's programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3ddrawing/conceptual/opengles_programmingguide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH7-SW23) for details.

Comment: I don't know iOS, but fragment shaders can not read from the frame buffer.  But, they can read from a texture which could have been used as a render target (FBO attachment).

Answer (score 0):

You need to write that code in the function which is called on color change.
and each time you need to set BlendFunc.

```
CGFloat red , green, blue;
// set red, green ,blue with desire color combination
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glColor4f(red* kBrushOpacity,
          green * kBrushOpacity,
          blue* kBrushOpacity,
                      kBrushOpacity);
```

To do more things by using BlendFunc [use this link](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glBlendFunc.xhtml)

Please specify if it works or not. It work for me.

Comment: This did not work for me, sorry. I tried setting the blend func on color change as well as right before drawing with no success.